# Adding a listener to each cell of the grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, uitableview

I've created a grid with the following HTML code and I was wondering whether it's possible to use jQuery to add a listener to each cell of the grid. The grid is drawn by drawing a box which contains horizontal and vertical lines that make the individual cell boxes. So currently each cell is not an individual element. I would like to add a listener per cell (or a listener that can differentiate between the cells) so that when I click on a cell, something specific to that cell happens.

Is this possible with my current setup? Or might I need to alter the way I'm creating the grid to make this happen?

```
<div class="grid-window" style="overflow: visible; top: 24px; left: 24px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; height: 225px; width: 215px;">
    <div class="grid" style="height: 225px; width: 215px;">
    <div class="gridlines">
        <div class="vline" style="height: 225px; left: 0px;"></div>
        <div class="vline" style="height: 225px; left: 30.571428571428573px;"></div>
        <div class="vline" style="height: 225px; left: 61.142857142857146px;"></div>
        <div class="vline" style="height: 225px; left: 91.71428571428572px;"></div>
        <div class="vline" style="height: 225px; left: 122.28571428571429px;"></div>
        <div class="vline" style="height: 225px; left: 152.85714285714286px;"></div>
        <div class="vline" style="height: 225px; left: 183.42857142857144px;"></div>
        <div class="hline" style="width: 100%; top: 0px;"></div>
        <div class="hline" style="width: 100%; top: 16px;"></div>
        <div class="hline" style="width: 100%; top: 32px;"></div>
        <div class="hline" style="width: 100%; top: 48px;"></div>
        <div class="hline" style="width: 100%; top: 64px;"></div>
        <div class="hline" style="width: 100%; top: 80px;"></div>
        <div class="hline" style="width: 100%; top: 96px;"></div>
        <div class="hline" style="width: 100%; top: 112px;"></div>
        <div class="hline" style="width: 100%; top: 128px;"></div>
        <div class="hline" style="width: 100%; top: 144px;"></div>
        <div class="hline" style="width: 100%; top: 160px;"></div>
        <div class="hline" style="width: 100%; top: 176px;"></div>
        <div class="hline" style="width: 100%; top: 192px;"></div>
        <div class="hline" style="width: 100%; top: 208px;"></div>
        <div class="hline" style="width: 100%; top: 224px;"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you formatting it this way instead of using a `<table>`?

Comment: Well, this code was part of a pre-written code set that creates the table using JavaScript (writing to HTML). I didn't bother changing this part of the code. Would changing this to a <table> make adding a listener easier?

Comment: Definitely! Then all you would need to do is:

    $("td").on("click", function(event) {
    
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to track which grid is clicked

You can calculate and store dimensions/boundaries of these cells and then track mouse location at the time of click simple function will tell you which cell is clicked.

I think it is best to alter the structure as it is not going to bear too well with content inside grids.

Nice HTML structure here as is the styling:

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2014/01/how-to-create-a-slidable-grid-with-jquery/

There is a HTML 5 plugin to add grids too don't know if it will help your case.

http://jquerygrid.net/

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a grid you should either use a table or a div with a border.

This way you can assign an id to each table cell or div.

Personally this is one of the times I would build a table - just assign a height of `30.57px` to each table row and a width of `30.57px` to the width of each column - then add `border:1px` as a style and you will have the same effect.